# Pick Top 3 - Cochran's Q?

Tags: binary-data, cochran-q, hypothesis-testing

I am trying to determine which statistical test to use. Participants were asked to choose the top 3 most important statements from a set of 15. I have read that Cochran's Q can be used to compare multiple binary outcomes. However, in this case, not every condition can be chosen nor can every condition rejected. Since exactly 3 conditions must be chosen and 12 conditions rejected, I'm not sure if any assumptions for the Cochran's Q test are being violated? Is Cochran's Q appropriate, or what statistical test would you suggest in order to determine if any statement(s) is/are more important?

Additional design information:

- The participants did not rank the statements.  They simply selected 3 statements as most important.
- All participants received the same list of statements, and the statements were always listed in the same order (unfortunately, randomization was not possible).

More specific questions include:

- Are men are more likely than women to put X statement in their top 3?
- Is statement X was more likely to be in the top 3 than statement Y?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did participants rank their top three statements or not?  Were all participants given the same list of statements?  Were the statements in the questionnaire always listed in the same order? (This doesn't much affect the test but it affects its interpretation.)  Could you be more specific about your study objectives?  ("If any statements are more important" is a good hint but it's vague.)

Comment: Thank you @whuber for your follow-up questions. I have updated the post.